# Fix warning Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent

Tags: javascript, seo, hotjar

While running the mobile friendly test I ran into this JavaScript console warning message: Hotjar not launching due to suspicious userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html). What would you recommend?

Comment: Did you search for "not launching due to suspicious userAgent" on this very site? There are a few hits for this exact message. If necessary, [edit] this one to tell us why those other Q&A did not solve your problem.

Comment: I did see the similar question, @clvrmnky, but it does not seem to apply to my case.

Comment: [Edit] the question and tell us what research you've done, including why thos other Q&A do not satisfy this question. There is not enough detail here otherwise.